# Downside of inline-block

Tags: css, margin

Imagine `h1` is inside a `div`:

Compare two styles: What is the problem with `inline-block`?

```css
h1 {
  display: block;
  Width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  Width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` trick works only for `display:block`, which will center the `h1` horizontally.

Comment: worth to note `inline-block` is buggy in old IE browsers, esp. IE7

Answer (score 2):

As their name implies, inline-blocks are laid inline. Auto margins have no effect on inline and inline-block boxes.

This isn't a "downside" or a "problem" with inline-blocks *per se*; it's just how inline formatting works. There is little reason to use an inline-block for anything other than putting a block container on a line box.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap `inline-block` styles around a block. That way you still get to control margins.

```
.wraper { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
.content { display: inline-block }
<div class="wrapper"><h1></h1></div>
```

You may add as many inline blocks and will just work.

Comment: Doen't Work or maybe i'm unable to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Well...a bit late, but still useful, I hope.

First of all: a visual example is here on the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/27ryxd31/).

Remember that "headings" are block-level elements (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)), so the `display:block;` is somewhat "implicit".

When you add the `display:inline-block;`, you are in fact removing the "block-level" element status thus making it behave differently: in your specific case, `margin: 0 auto` means 0-pixels margins on top and bottom, while 0-pixels margin on the left and "whatever it is" on the right. Just like any text on your page. So, you could add something after the `<h1>` tag, to have it show up inline (of course) with the heading (see JSFiddle example).

On a `display:block;` element, on the contrary, the left and right margins would be calculated so that the element remains on the center of the parent.